# Adding threshold to the metadata count - Salesforce 2GP packaging

Tags: managed-package, isv, unlocked-package

For the Salesforce packaging, there is a limit of 10,000 metadata components. We have several packages and we once reached that limit for one of the packages and had to make a lot of last-minute changes to the package failing.

We are creating an unlocked package first and then we are converting to a managed package.
Is there any way, we can add some checks to the earlier threshold so that we'll have some time to gracefully handle the situation.

Looking forward to any sfdx commands,bash scripts, or any apex native ways so that we will have ourselves notified before this limit.

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing a full deployment, the [deployResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deployresult.htm) gives you information about the total number of components. Thus, you could actually do this in a number of ways, such as adding a commit hook to run a validation deployment without unit tests to confirm the official size, and read that data, potentially rolling back the commit with an error if a threshold is met. Note that if this managed package is an ISV product bound for the AppExchange, you won't need to worry about the 10,000 file limit, as that limit is 35,000 as of the time of this answer. Check [deploy()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm) for more information about package size limits.

Comment: About 35,000 limit - it says 10K is it not the same? 
Maximum number of files in packages 10,000

Comment: @YsrShk *Maximum number of files in AppExchange packages 35,000*